# Buttons carousel for iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios

I need a UIButton's or UIImageView's carousel like the one in the image attached. I searched in Cocoa Controls, but there's nothing like it.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is no carousel class in iOS SDK. But you can always look for 3rd party libraries.

[Like this one](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel)

The example image you posted seems to be created with a lot of 3D work. I don't think you can create the same look with just dragging controls from XCode.

Answer (score 1):

[iCarousel](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/icarousel) may be a good start.

There is no "circular" disposition but maybe you can use the library to achieve what you want.